# Linux tool/editor that will nicely auto-format my code AFTER it's written

Tags: indentation, auto-indent

I'm looking for a tool or editor where I can paste in potentially messy code, be it HTML, Javascript, CSS, whatever, and properly take care of all indentation and spacing.

I use Geany but I don't see an option for this, surprisingly. I don't know if it's possible in vim or emacs. Any help would be appreciated.

Example HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul>
<li>what a mess</li> 
</ul>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You can install IntelliJ Idea. Then you create a html/css/js file there, paste your code, let IntelliJ do a nice formatting (works even with minified css/js!) and then copy it back to your actual IDE. Although I strongly recommend IntelliJ on Linux. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both vim and emacs will let you do what you ask. I believe in vim you want to use 'gg=G', and emacs is C-x C-M-\

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what C-M-\ means. I hit Ctrl-x followed by Ctrl-M then \ and that didn't work. Ctrl-M Ctrl-\ didn't work either. And the vim 'gg=G' did nothing. See above, I added the test HTML content I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Tried gg=G on a .js file, made a mess out of it. Is there some vim option I need turned on somewhere first?

Comment: In emacs C-M-\ means Control+Meta(Alt key)+\ It is a lovely 3 key chord, which is reasonably common in emacs. Vim shouldn't need anything selected for that to work. gg goes to the start of your file (you can also use 1G I believe), = starts to fix the indenting, and G takes it to the end.

Comment: vim will need :set ft=html first if you start with an unnamed file. Also if you like an IDE Aptana will do this for you too.

Comment: Thanks. There was some missing stuff, I had to set up smart indentation. Actually I found some "ultimate .vimrc file" and once I used that, the gg=G trick worked.

Comment: You better have indent installed, or gg=G will crash Vim.

Answer (score 0):

There are some command line tools that can help (eg, 'indent' for C), but 'Edd's suggestion of Emacs and vi are probably the best that will work on all languages.

Answer (score 0):

You could reformat/pretty-print the starting HTML and then work with the resulting file in the editor of your choice. For example on Linux you could use [Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/documentation/) to clean up the HTML before editing it; you'd use a command like this,

```
tidy -indent ugly_file.html > nicer_file.html
```

*(thank you to @shmit in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400827/9624052) for the pointer to Tidy)*