# Format HTML from the command line

Tags: html, autoformatting

Is it possible to format HTML automatically with a tool, similar to how ESLint formats JavaScript? 
Why does it seem that there aren't many customizable options that you can integrate as part of your development pipeline?

I would wish to format HTML in the following way automatically with a command run from the terminal:

```html
<input
  class="input-style"
  placeholder="Replace me!"
/>
```

For example, I could `npm run html-lint` and it would fix the syntax in HTML files and warn about cases it can't fix.

Comment: You seem to have managed to format it that way. What's the problem? Or as you asking for a tool recommendation? Recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do this automatically with a tool, that you can customise in a similar way to eslint.

Comment: As I said, recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is even possible though. Hard to find a single tool that would accomplish this.

Comment: Use something like "Visual Studio Code" editor and add some extension that is meant to beautify HTML. Is that what you need?

Comment: I want a script that i can add to package.json that i can use to automatically format code and also warn about cases that it cant fix, similar to eslint

Comment: [As pointed out by Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53278632#comment93439513_53278632), software recommendation questions are off-topic at Stack Overflow.
I have re-asked more or less [the same question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/87737) where it is ON-topic.
[My self-answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/87738) builds on [the highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400992) here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe what you are looking for is prettier, this also supports CLI, even you can also make config, see the complete documentation here. [Prettier CLI](https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers. Prettier seems to by default use the html format I asked for in the question.

Answer (score 8):

[`js-beautify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify) also works on HTML.

```
npm install js-beautify
js-beautify --type html file.html
```

Notice all this beautifying makes the file size increase substantially. The indentation is great for revision and editing, but not so much for hosting. For that reason, you might find `html-minifier` equally useful.

Comment: Has the added benefit that it also works for partial HTML (and with errors). Unlike tidy, which only works on perfect HTML.

Answer (score 4):

I personally think tidy is a fantastic options for tidying up HTML files. Checkout [Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/documentation/)

Answer (score 3):

I Googled for "Package json pretty print html" and got the following:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty

(It's not clear whether this can be included in `package.json`)

There's also this (appears to be a command-line tool):

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify